# Google Analytics Events - Triggering a user exit

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am looking for a way to **simulate** with Google Analytics `_gaq.push` that **the user has left the page** (so GA stops counting on Average time on site).

This is some code I use to track AJAX pages in Google Analytics (it counts a page view):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/ajax/save']);
```

What I am looking for is something such as:

```
_gaq.push(['_exitCurrentPage', 'http://example.com/']);
```

Does anything with that functionality exist?

Thanks in advance,

Xavi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there's any specific functionality in GA for this but you could just set a cookie called something like `dont_track` then set it to simulate the page exit. You could then check for the cookie's existence before calling your normal tracking code and stop execution if it exists.

Comment: I have a one-page tool which is 100% JavaScript and can't track how much time users spend there, guess I'll need to use Clicktale or something else than Google Analytics. Thanks Ewan!